# Drush PHP Path Issue

Tags: drush

I've searched for an answer, but can't figure this out.

I've got PHP 5.4 installed on a server.  I've installed the latest 7.x branch of Drupal (7.39) and installed DRUSH via `pear`.

Now, whenever I type `drush status`, I get this:

```
[JAM 04:30:00 drush] > drush status
The following restricted PHP modes have non-empty values:                [error]
disable_functions. This configuration is incompatible with drush. 
Please check your configuration settings in /etc/php.ini or in your
drush.ini file; see examples/example.drush.ini for details.
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php                                                                       
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php.ini /etc/drush.ini /usr/share/pear/drush/drush.ini /root/.drush/drush.ini  
 PHP OS                :  Linux                                                                              
 Drush version         :  6.2.0                                                                              
 Drush configuration   :                                                                                     
 Drush alias files     :
```

You can see that I've put a `drush.ini` in `/etc/` and I point to it using the `DRUSH_INI` environment var. I've also put it in my `~/.drush/drush.ini` and also in the `drush` install folder.

The issue I'm having is that it is always reading the regular `php.ini` first, and giving the error message about `disable_functions`.  I want the WEB to continue using the `/etc/php.ini`, but I'm trying to override the drush ini file, and it works (see the status) and recognizes the new files, but always picks up the `/etc/php.ini` first.

How do I get it to IGNORE the `/etc/php.ini` and only use the `drush.ini`?

Comment: I've also tried using the PHP_INI environment var also, but it does the same thing.  It adds it to the list, but still processes the /etc/php.ini first.

Comment: Your drush could be a bit old (`6.2.0`), so try upgrading it via [composer](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) to: `7.x` or `8.0-dev` and see if that helps.